# Does "it" refer to the whole situation or the previous sentence?

Tags: meaning, pronouns

What does ***it*** refer to? As a pronoun, does it refer to the whole situation or the previous sentence?

> The images are gut-wrenching. In one video, a man tries to revive a
> child, a boy perhaps three or four years old, by pouring water over
> his face, rubbing him, attempting a futile resuscitation. The boy is
> pale and limp and appears to have died. Around him there are more
> bodies in similar states of death or near-death, prostrate on a floor.
> Men move around with the kinetic energy of those overwhelmed by a
> catastrophe and lacking the knowledge and the tools to save the
> victims. Oddly, there is no blood. ***It*** is as if everyone has
> drowned.

[Syria, Assad, and the History of Chemical Weapons](https://www.newyorker.com/news/news-desk/syria-assad-and-the-history-of-chemical-weapons#:%7E:text=It%20is%20as%20if%20everyone%20has%20drowned.%20)

Answer (score 5):

The next to the last sentence makes the last sentence make sense.

I think the "it" refers to the whole situation but you can make a case for its referring just to the previous sentence. The meaning is essentially the same in either case.